# How to get context sensitive help in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Years ago I used Visual Studio for Windows and always appreciated the great context sensitive help that tool you directly to the MSDN page for the class/function your cursor was on then you typed F1. I'm not using VS for Mac and I can't find similar functionality. Does it exist?

I did find that Alt-Command-? opens some tool called MonoDoc, but it doesn't seem to be context sensitive and doesn't seem very useful to me as I can't really find the class I'm interested in very easily.

Interestingly, the goto definition functionality (Command-D) works fine, and the resulting source code has documentation in the comments, I just can't find any easy way to see that documentation rendered.

I know I can go to MSDN directly and search there, but that is much less convenient than the context sensitive help that I remember.